# Errror in npm run build

Tags: npm, build

Running npm run build but keep getting this error
sh: --: invalid option
Usage:  sh [GNU long option] [option] ...
sh [GNU long option] [option] script-file ...
GNU long options:
--debug
--debugger
--dump-po-strings
--dump-strings
--help
--init-file
--login
--noediting
--noprofile
--norc
--posix
--protected
--rcfile
--restricted
--verbose
--version
--wordexp
Shell options:
-irsD or -c command or -O shopt_option          (invocation only)
-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP or -o option

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXPOS.jpg)
Please help

Comment: Normal screenshots are already frowned upon (see [ask]), but pointing your phone at your screen is much worse.